# Is there an equivalent to the eventAfterAllRender callback in version 4?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm refactoring a project originally done with version 3.4. I need to add a tabindex to event elements based on event order, previously I was using eventAfterAllRender, but I can't seem to find an equivalent in v4, is it there? What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, from the documentation. What is it that you need the callback for, exactly? Perhaps there's another way to do your task.

Comment: Ok sorry, having re-read your question I can see your already wrote what you are wanting to do. Are you supplying the events from server-side code? You should be able to work out the event order based on the dates (unless you also have a custom [eventOrder](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder) setting, or are using multiple event sources. If those constraints don't apply, then you could then add a custom property to each event server-side showing its eventual order in the calendar, and then in eventRender, use that to add the tabindex to the element.

Comment: That's the first solution that popped into my head, but it's not to say there isn't another way. It does seem odd they removed that callback though, perhaps you could raise a feature request to have it reinstated

Comment: Events are coming from multiple google calendar sources, but I suppose I could grab those server-side (already doing so to handle updates so not too much extra work) and then feed them in with the custom property as you suggested, thanks for the idea! I'll probably also submit the feature request because it does seem like an odd thing to omit.

Comment: Hm...I just found https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3 which says of "eventAfterAllRender": `Removed. The concecpt of event rendering being fully complete is flawed (such as when events are revealed in a +more popup). You should operate on individual events instead, via eventPositioned or use some other callback.`. Having read that, I'm not sure I fancy your chances with the feature request, sorry...

Comment: Good catch, I missed that. I guess handling it server side is the way to go. Thanks for your help