# Need a replacement for onEventAfterAllRender?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

i need onEventAfterAllRender to perform some operations after i have rendered all my calendar events.

Since this feature has been removed from v4 i need  some other way to do it!!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do after the events have rendered? Perhaps there is a different way to achieve your goal. If you explain in more detail what you're trying to do, we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: In the meantime, this question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641641/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-eventafterallrender-callback-in-version-4 . The discussion there might be interesting to you as well.